# CLion Profiler: "No profiler data" message after stopping the process

Tags: c, profiling, clion, profiler

I am developing a C project and I need to profile it to understand where I can optimize it. I am using the CLion IDE and I tried their profiler tool without success.

The Profiler starts without any problem, however when I stop the process and go to the Profiler tab it shows the message *"No profiler data"*:
[image]

I have defined a custom output path for the profiler data file in **Settings | Build, Execution, Deployment | Dynamic Analysis Tools | Perf**, and the data file is being successfully created and filled while the process runs. But in the end, CLion seems unable to read.

I have no experience with profilers. This was my first time trying to profile my program. What might be the problem here? Any suggestion?

Comment: I also bumped into this issue. The perf file is located in /tmp and can be opened with Hotspot program. But this is pretty annoying that CLion itself cannot open it. I'm using Remote to profile on Raspberry Pi. What about yours?

Answer (score 0):

## Generic Steps

1. Get the PID of the process you're profiling.
2. Send a SIGINT signal to that process.

## Background

Unfortunately CLion doesn't have a way to send a SIGINT signal, which Ctrl+C normally does on the command line. Instead it goes straight to SIGKILL, which will usually (but not always?) stop the profiler.

To interrupt your process, you'll need to send a SIGINT to the PID of your process.

## Linux

1. Get the PID

   $ pgrep my_process
   12345
2. Send the SIGINT signal to that PID
   sudo kill -s SIGINT 12345